# Dividing logarithms without using a calculator

Tags: logarithms

The problem I have is:
 $\log16+\log25-\log36\over{\log10-\log3}$

(log is base 10 here)

I have the answer as 2 but no idea how to reach it..

I need to work this out without the use of a calculator but I can't get my head round it.
I know that $\log(16) = \log(4^2) = 2(\log4)$
$\log25 = 2(\log5) $

I can add \logs together when they all are a power of the same number e.g. $\log(64) + \log(32) = \log(2^6) + \log(2^5) = 6(\log2) + 5(\log2) = 11(\log2)$.

I might just be over thinking it or over complicating it but I'd really appreciate some help here.
Thanks.

Comment: 2 is the answer :) Use $\log a + \log b - \log c = \log \frac{ab}{c}$

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention I know the answer, but no idea how to actually work it out. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

$\log16+\log25-\log36=\log(\frac{16\cdot25}{36})=\log((\frac{4\cdot5}{6})^2)=2\log(\frac{20}{6})=2\log(\frac{10}{3})$

$\log10-\log3=\log(\frac{10}{3})$

$\frac{2\log(\frac{10}{3})}{\log(\frac{10}{3})}=2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use $\log a +\log b=\log ab$ and $\log a -\log b=\log \frac{a}{b}$